# C program having issues inside "fork()" and pipes

Tags: c, pipe, fork, ipc

Hi I am a very beginner in parent and child communication in C. I am trying to build a calculator with C programming that would just read the data from the file compute some calculations using `fork()` and `pipe` and then determine the output. I was able to read the operators from the file and also the numbers from the file but I am having trouble in in using `dup` inside the `if(fork() == 0)` condition. Everything which is above `close(1);` is working but everything after that is not working. I am using input stream 0 to read the first argument, use stream 3 to read the 2nd argument and use standard output stream 1 for output. I know after that I have to just setup conditions for addition, subtraction, multiplication and division and then use `execl` to compute the calculations after I figure that out but I am not able to figure out why I am having that problem any help will be appreciated thanks!. Here is the code and input file below. In order the program, we need to pass the file name as the argument. For example `./calc data.txt`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MAXLEN 1000

int fds[100][2];
char operators[100];

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char line[MAXLEN], *temp;

    FILE *dataFile = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    //read the first line - it contains the configuration
    fgets(line, MAXLEN, dataFile);

    // sample content for line: a + b - c
    strtok(line, " \n"); //skip the symbol representing variable/parameter
    int count=0;
    while (temp = strtok(NULL, " \n")) {
            operators[count] = temp[0];
            printf("operator: %c\n", operators[count]);
            count++;
            strtok(NULL, " \n"); //skip the symbol representing variable/parameter
    }
    int x[count+1];
    int num = 0;
    while (fscanf(dataFile, "%d", &x[num]) > 0){
            printf("%d\n", x[num]);
            num++;
            }
    for(int h=0; h<count*2+1; h++){
            pipe(fds[h]);
            printf("%d \n",h);
    }
    printf("Count: %d\n", count);
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
            //printf("%c\n", operators[i]);
            if (fork() == 0){
                    //printf("Value of operators: %c\n",operators[i]);
                    close(0);
                    dup(fds[2*i][0]);
                    close(3);
                    dup(fds[2*i+1][0]);
                    //printf("After close(3)\n");
                    if(operators[i] == '+')
                            printf("Add \n");
                    close(1);
                    printf("After close(0) \n");
                    dup(fds[2*i+2][1]);
                    printf("Value of operators: %c\n", operators[i]);
            if(operators[i] == '+')
                            printf("Add %n");
            }`
          }
   }`
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're using `fork` for this? You're creating a process for every operator in the input. I'm not sure if that's really what you want to do.

Comment: I was being told to use fork

Comment: OT: regarding: `FILE *dataFile = fopen(argv[1], "r");`  Never access beyond `argv[0]` with out first checking `argc` to assure that the user actually entered the expected command line parameter

Comment: OT: Please do not use <tab> for indenting.  Each editor is setup to use a specific number of characters for a <tab> (with the default being 8 characters)  Strongly suggest using 4 spaces for each indent level

Comment: regarding: `while (temp = strtok(NULL, " \n")) `  an assignment always  results in `true` which is not what you want.  Suggest:  `while ( (temp = strtok(NULL, " \n"))) ) ` (notice the extra parens) which will be checking the contents of `temp` for != NULL

Comment: regarding: `printf("Add %n");`  What are you expecting this statement to do?  BTW: it does not compile!

Comment: Each OS has a limited number of 'child' processes that a user is allowed to create.  This code could easily exceed that limit

Comment: Each OS has a limited number of pipes that a user is allowed to generate.  Most likely, 100 pipes is beyond that limit

Comment: regarding statements like: `strtok(NULL, " \n");`  this stops for every space character (unless multiple space characters)  similarly for a '\n' character.  Therefore, `a+b-c` would fail to extract the individual items.  Note: this statement does NOT skip/ignore variable names

Comment: regarding calls to C library functions, like: `pipe()`. always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: OT: Note: the `fork()` function has three kinds of returned values: <0 indicates the function failed.  ==0 indicates in the child process.  >0  indicates in the parent process.   The code needs to check for all three conditions

Comment: @user3629249 Regarding `strtok(NULL, " \n")`, I will have to use that because that's how I have to do it. And regarding for the return values of `fork()`, I am going to implement that but right now I know `fork()==0` so I want to get the main part knocked out. Regarding `printf` statement, I am going to use `execl` instead of `printf` but I was just checking if that statement is working or not. Regarding that while loop, I am using your suggestion. I will check for `argc` later. But first I want to get the main part knocked out.

Answer (score 1):

File descriptor 1 refers to `stdout`. If you close that, your call to `printf` will fail because it attempts to print to a closed stream.

Comment: Then how can I do that? because I have to also check for operators in order to calculate. How can I do that?

Comment: How can you do what? You can close file descriptor 1 exactly the way you do with `close(1)`. But file descriptor 1 refers to `stdout` - the standard output stream, i.e. your terminal. When you close that, you can't print output to it anymore.

Comment: How can I make sure that the if condition which is after `close(1)` is working? Because at the end that's what I need and also can i use `execl` inside that if condition is it going to work?

Comment: @eliesmith The condition should work fine. The problem is the `printf` that you call when that condition is true. It errors because it can't print to the stream you just closed. Please read some introduction to standard I/O - and also processes and fork, because judging from the code, it doesn't look like you have the right idea about how to use that.

Comment: can you help mw with that? I have to do that for all mathematical operators

Comment: @eliesmith I think you have misunderstood your assignment. Creating a new process for every operator to calculate the result is ludicrous, and it would create quite a bit of complexity because then you have racing conditions to deal with. Are you sure your assignment wasn't to pipe the instructions to a process created with fork and then send back the results from that process to the main process?

Comment: This is what I have "Read the first line from the data file and create the necessary # of children and setup IPC configuration ignoring the operator precedence rules - simply setup to process the equation left to right. Main program should read the remaining lines, send the values to appropriate pipes, and get the result and print in the screen."